# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' in Deeplabcut

Tags: tensorflow

I installed Deeplabcut in Anaconda env and activate Deeplabcut env.
Then I used ipython and tried to import deeplabcut and got this error. could anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this error? Thank you.

```
`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import deeplabcut

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\__init__.py:16
     13 import os
     15 # Suppress tensorflow warning messages
---> 16 import tensorflow as tf
     18 tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
     19 DEBUG = True and "DEBUG" in os.environ and os.environ["DEBUG"]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`
```

I installed tensorflow package separately and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please install `deeplabcut` module using below code and then import it:

```
pip install 'deeplabcut[gui,tf]'
import deeplabcut
```

Output:

[image]

Kindly refer to [How To Install DeepLabCut](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/main/docs/installation.md) link for more details on the installation process by considering conda, TensorFlow and technical requirements. Let us know if the issue still persists.